# Strange folder behaviour in Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, computer-behavior

I found a strange issue when trying to upload some folders to a cloud service, which weren't recognized by the software. The folder would appear to be hidden, but it's not marked as such and the checkbox is greyed out:

[image: Folder Image]

(Nascosto = Hidden)

If I try to check the folder though cmd, it does not show when I type `dir` but appears if I do `dir /a`:

[image: CMD image]

I would really like to understand what is going on. It appears only this folder, and others inside it, show this behaviour. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the output of `attrib Documents`?

Comment: It is `S         H:\pen drive\Documents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I would really like to understand what is going on

> What is the output of attrib Documents?
>
> It is `S     H:\pen drive\Documents`

Your `Document` folder has the `System` attribute (The file is a system file and should not be manipulated by the user.)

`dir` by default will not display files or directories with system or hidden attributes.

`dir /a` will show **all** files.

To remove the `System` attribute from your folder run the following command:

```
attrib -S Documents
```

Example:

```
> attrib +S Documents

> dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          .
02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,696,394,248,192 bytes free

> dir /a
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          .
02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          ..
02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          Documents
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  1,696,394,248,192 bytes free

> attrib -S Documents

> dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\test

02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          .
02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          ..
02/04/2017  22:41    <DIR>          Documents
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  1,696,394,248,192 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [attrib](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) - Display or change file attributes.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I find it strange, though, that normal folders have been marked as system folders out of nowhere. Could there be any reason for that?

Comment: @LuigiPiccoli Hmm. Did you copy the folder from somewhere else?

Comment: Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also see [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Yes, I have copied it from a USB drive

Comment: @LuigiPiccoli Copying files or folders will preserve any attributes where possible (as long as they are supported by the underlying file system).

Comment: I see. Maybe could it have something to do with the fact that the folders have standard names (Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos)? Could it be that the USB Stick came with those folders already set as system ones?

Comment: @LuigiPiccoli Could be. Take a look at the USB Stick. Otherwise I don't know where it came from. The standard folders on my C drive don't have the System attribute.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you again for your answer :)

Comment: This solved my problem. My folder was SH, so it was hidden, and I couldn't click the button. Thanks